# Soft keyboard not appear on screen when i press next or prev button

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an Android app using PhoneGap. I am facing a problem with the "prev" and "next" buttons on the keyboard. When the I click the "prev" button, the cursor moves to the previous text input field and clicking on "next" button makes the cursor move to the next text field in the view. But my problem is that the keyboard does not appear on the screen. This issue only exist when I press "next" and "prev" button. Direct clicking on text box it works fine.

And i am using "Phonegap 2.4"

And below is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.apptivoapp.ApptivoApps"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="locale|navigation|orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" 
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Html code

```
<article class="signup_wrapper">
<ul class="regbox " data-role="none">
  <li>
    <input id="ftName" name="FtName" type="text" placeholder="First name" data-role="none"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="ltName" name="LtName" type="text" placeholder="Last name" data-role="none"/>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Are you talking about hardware previous and next buttons, or the ones on the soft keyboard?

Comment: i am talking about soft keyboard.

Comment: OK, but to press these, then the keyboard should already be visible on the screen. When does it NOT appear?

Comment: yes right shade. but it will hide when i press next or prev button

Comment: Could you post some code related to the problem? Also, which version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: update my post with phonegap version and sample code i am using.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: no @shade now also i am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your manifest file. You are instructing your keyboard to hide whenever the window itself gets focused, which probably happens during the transition from one field to another. You need to change the following line:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
```

...to this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```